May I review my deleted questions
Some of my questions actually get tons of upvotes and deleted anyway. May I examine them so I understand what's the problem.

I have checked and the deleted questions on cogsci.se have -4, -3, -5, -3, and -4 votes. Thus, you have no deleted questions on cogsci.se with upvotes. 
If you are sincere about asking better questions, you may want to do things like:

increase the amount of initial research you do before asking a question.
improve the quality of expression on questions (e.g., grammar, spelling, etc.).
reduce the number of unfounded assumptions
try to adopt a clearer structure to your questions (e.g., start with what you know and understand, and culminate in a clear and answerable question)

Most active users on this site do welcome questions from people who have little background in psychology and cognitive science. However, the questions need to be answerable. If you are having the majority of your questions closed, this may be a sign that you should learn a bit more about psychology and cognitive science in general before asking more questions.

Including a question whether prostitution is a substitute for marriage (having positive cross elasticity). That one is downvoted too?

@JimThio That one was migrated from Economics to here and after giving it a shot was deemed to be ill-fit here. See Josh's answer for more details.

The questions on your account which were deleted are:

Are prostitution and marriage substitutes? [closed] +1 / -4, 2 flags, migrated from economics.stackexchange.com May 1 at 12:59, closed as off topic by H.Muster, Artem Kaznatcheev, Chuck Sherrington, Ben Brocka, Josh Gitlin♦ May 28 at 14:09, deleted by Josh Gitlin♦ May 28 at 16:48
How can false beliefs be profitable? [closed] +0 / -3, 3 flags, closed as not constructive by Chuck Sherrington, H.Muster, Ben Brocka, Jeromy Anglim♦ May 28 at 13:09, deleted by Josh Gitlin♦ May 28 at 16:48
What is the difference between cognitive function and psychology? [closed] +0 / -4, 1 flag, closed as not constructive by Chuck Sherrington, Jeromy Anglim♦ May 28 at 12:20, deleted by Josh Gitlin♦ May 28 at 16:48
Can 2 people lie to each other and yet benefit each other? [closed] +0 / -5, 2 flags, closed as not a real question by Artem Kaznatcheev, Chuck Sherrington, Ben Brocka, Jeromy Anglim♦ May 28 at 0:04, deleted by Josh Gitlin♦ May 28 at 16:48.

I deleted these questions in an attempt to keep the site clean. If you would like to make a case for a particular question to be undeleted, I.E. so that you could improve it and try and have it reopened, I will undelete so that you can attempt to improve them.
None of the questions had any answers, except for Are prostitution and marriage substitutes? which has a +14 answer. This was a good question, just not for our site. It was migrated from Economics in an attempt to save it (because that site is being closed) but unfortunately our community did not feel it was on-topic.

Thanks a lot Josh Giftin. Well, that prostitution thingy is a hybrid between economy and psychology. I mean the idea that humans have utility function and make decision is a psychological model right?
